# Most probable number of clusters

Tags: probability, clustering

I have a set `S` of `N` 2D points, each point `P` is associated with a doubly infinite cone `Cone(P)` with vertical axis, apex in `P` and angle `a`.

```
Cluster(A, S):
    union all
        (
          {A, B} union Cluster(B, S excluding A)
          where {A, B} belongs to S and A intersects with Cone(B)
        )
```

I know the bounding box of the set `S`, the number of points `N` and the cone angle.

`h` = height of the bounding box
`w` = width of the bounding box

I need to find the most probable number of unique clusters in a set S.

```
M = F(w,h,N,a) ?
```

Actually this will be used as a means of choosing a maximum cone angle `a` small enough for the points to form at least M clusters.

This way the problem could be stated as:

```
a = Y(w,h,N,M) ?
```

*Just to help you imagine, it could be illustrated as the shadows of a set of parallel strings with sun moving by the angle `a`.
If a line shadows another one at any time - they both belong to same cluster.*

Comment: Position of bounding box is irrelevant, because i only know the width and height. The problem could be solved in terms of just average density of points and the height and the angle. This way i would be finding the average density of clusters.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the condition that the cone is with vertical axis and its apex is $P$.

Comment: It seems that your relation "in the same cluster" is not transitive, meaning "$A$ and $B$ are in the same cluster" and "$B$ and $C$ are in the same cluster" don't imply "$A$ and $C$" are in the same cluster".

Comment: Doesn't it sound a little strange? $A$ and $B$ are in the same cluster, $B$ and $C$ are in the same cluster, but $A$ and $C$ are **NOT** in the same cluster. So maybe your "cluster" is different from the "cluster" in machine learning?

Comment: C is not a point, it's a Cone. C(A, a) is the cone with apex A and angle a

Comment: The $C$ in my last comment is a point, abusing the notations. You can replace it with some other notation.

Comment: You need to clarify whether the relation defining the clusters is meant to be the transitive hull of the symmetric relation you've defined. Unless your relation is an equivalence relation (which means it's transitive), it's not clear what could be meant by counting clusters defined by it. Also, there's a contradiction between the title and the body of the question; the title says you're interested in the expected number of clusters and the body says you're interested in the most probable number of clusters.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's transitive definitely.

Comment: Your edit doesn't reflect that it's transitive; you're only taking a single step. You also need that $A\in C(B,a)$, $B\in C(D,a)$ and $D\in C(E,a)$ imply $A\in C(E,a)$, etc., that is, you need to take the entire transitive hull of the relation you've defined, which can be defined e.g. as the intersection of all transitive relations that contain the relation.